# how to allow users registered in my wordpress website, to charge pictures in specific cells of a table

Tags: php, wordpress, web-frontend, wordpress-plugin-creation

hi guys i hope to explain well what i need to do.
I have a buddyboss website where users are registered with gravity forms. we are an actor agency, so i want to create a layout where actors can insert their best pictures for create a composit of pictures.
i tried before to create a script JS with a png layout , but doesn-t works.

So i had anoher idea, that was create a page with a table and allow to users to charge in some of their cells their pictures. but i m blocked and i don-t know how to do it
i don't know how to write a code for, or if there exist some plugin that allow users to customize .

i need that users charge pictures in the central cell of column 1, and in the 4 central cells of the second column.
i hope someone can give me some idea, or code, because i am 0 with php
here is the table code.

```
<table style="width: 1600px; height: 1200px; border-collapse: collapse; border: 1px solid black;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="width: 50%; border: 1px solid black;">
<table style="width: 100%; height: 100%; border-collapse: collapse;">
<tbody>
<tr style="height: 5%;">
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 85%;">
<td style="border: 1px solid black;">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 10%;">
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
<td style="width: 50%; border: 1px solid black;">
<table style="width: 100%; height: 100%; border-collapse: collapse;">
<tbody>
<tr style="height: 2%;">
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 48%;">
<td style="border: 1px solid black; width: 50%; padding: 10px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="border: 1px solid black; width: 50%; padding: 10px;">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 48%;">
<td style="border: 1px solid black; width: 50%; padding: 10px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 10px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="border: 1px solid black; width: 50%; padding: 10px;">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 2%;">
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

i tried before with JS to create a script but doesn't work. so i hope someone can explain me how to write a php code for fo it

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that I got everything right. So you want the user to upload his picture to your server so they can personalize their own page ?

First of all just to clarify : JavaScript is a client-side script language. Meaning that **you can't upload an image on your server using only JavaScript**. You will be able to load an image on the current document but as soon as you will refresh the page it will disapear.
Thus, you need a PHP interaction to save files on the server (you can make javascript dialogue with PHP for instance). PHP is the language that runs on your server and not JavaScript.

If you are looking for a PHP solution : (maybe finding a WordPress pluging would be easier)

But in HTML / PHP you can do it like this :

**HTML :**

```
<form action="post_img.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="userImage" id="userImage" type="file">
    <input type="submit" name="upload" value="Clic here to submit the image">
</form>
```

**PHP : (in the file "post_img.php")**

```
if (! empty($_POST["upload"])) {
    if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userImage']['tmp_name'])) {
        $targetPath = "img/" . $_FILES['userImage']['name'];//The destination of your file
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userImage']['tmp_name'], $targetPath)) {
            echo "The file has been successfully uploaded !";
        }
    }
}
```

Now the image of the user is uploaded on your server. However there are multiple issues :

1. You have no way to recognize which user uploaded the image
2. **There is nothing guaranteeing that the file is actualy an image** and not something else. The image format can also be png, jpg, gif...
3. The image **can be of any ratio / size** (however if you run on a PHP server there is an upload size limit (default: 2Mo) that you can change.

This is why you wanna improve the PHP code.

1. First I would **use the same format for every images** (JPEG is the best
   because the images will be lighter, if you wanna handle transparency
   use PNG instead) and limit the image size, plus eventualy normalize the ratio depending on your needs.
   To do so I suggest that you look at the PHP documentation for functions such as *ImageCreateTrueColor()*, *imagejpeg()*, *imagecopyresampled()*, *imagecreatefromjpeg()*... (I don't have it in mind but you can find plenty of examples on Internet". Here is the documentation : https://www.php.net/docs.php).
   I have to warn you that it can quickly become pretty hard task to cover every possible image formats, size... if you are not used to code.
2. Secondly you should for instance give to the images the name of the user id in your database, or store in a table of the database the path to the user's image. So you can see who uploaded the image.

I hope that it helped you. I think that the problem that you will have is that if you are using a WordPress website, you are not directly managing the database, so you might struggle understanding how the user ids are stored etc...
I would rather find a WordPress solution if I where you.

PS : If you manage to store the images on your server, then you can use CSS/JavaScript to create a composit of pictures. If that was your question, yes you can use CSS grids, or CSS flexboxes...

Comment: FIRST OF ALL THANK YOU FOR ANSWERING.